# Define types directly in tuple like SML?

Tags: haskell, types, tuples, sml

I remember this from SML and *The Little MLer*

```
fun has_steak (_ : meza, Steak : main, _ : dessert) = true
| has_steak _ = false
```

In other words, the types of the 3-tuple are being established in-line, so to speak without an explicit type declaration. So if I have this in Haskell

```
data Meza = Shrimp | Calamari | Escargots | Hummus deriving (Show,Eq)
data Main = Steak | Ravioli | Chicken | Eggplant deriving (Show,Eq)
data Salad = Green | Cucumber | Greek deriving (Show,Eq)
data Dessert = Sundae | Mousse | Torte deriving (Show,Eq)
```

This

```
hasSteak :: (Meza,Main,Dessert) -> Bool
hasSteak (_,Steak,_) = True
hasSteak _ = False
```

works fine, but could I do something similar to the in-line SML above in Haskell? This doesn't work

```
hasSteak ((_::Meza),Steak,(_::Dessert)) = True
hasSteak _ = False
```

and this

```
hasSteak (_,Steak,_) :: (Meza,Main,Dessert) = True
hasSteak _ = False
```

doesn't fly either. It seems I've seen this sort of "in-line" type defining in another context, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You say this doesn't work:

```
hasSteak ((_::Meza),Steak,(_::Dessert)) = True
hasSteak _ = False
```

But the error it gives says `Type signatures are only allowed in patterns with ScopedTypeVariables`. All you have to do is turn on the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension (with `:set -XScopedTypeVariables` at the GHCi prompt or `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` in a .hs file), and then it will work and do exactly what you want.

Comment: Could you (or someone) elaborate on what this is and why it's needed?

Comment: @147pm Sure, the authors of the extension themselves have elaborated at length on both questions in the Fine Manual. If you still have questions after reading the section on ScopedTypeVariables, you should at least be able to make your questions more targeted.

Comment: “The Fine Manual” being presumably https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html?highlight=scopedtypevariables#pattern-type-signatures. But that doesn't explain why pattern type sigs are enabled by, of all extensions, `-XScopedTypeVariables`, since they don't really have anything to do with type variables. Honestly I think it's just a historical glitch that standard Haskell doesn't support pattern signatures, and the fix for that ended up in `ScopedTypeVariables` somewhat accidentally.

Comment: @leftaroundabout The [overview](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html#overview) at your link shows why it is part of `ScopedTypeVariables`: because the pattern can bind type variables, not just term variables.

Comment: @DanielWagner well, ok – without `-XScopedTypeVariables`, pattern signatures including variables couldn't work. But it would still be perfectly possible and useful to allow for _monomorphic_ pattern signatures.

Comment: What is meant by "term variable?"

Comment: @147pm A “term variable” is an ordinary variable, like the `x` in `id x = x`.  The distinction is with “type variables”, which are the variables that appear in parametric types, such as the `a` in `id :: a -> a`.  A term variable appears in terms (aka expressions, aka at the value level), a type variable appears in types; a term variable refers to a term (aka expression), a type variable refers to a type.